# Common Date format for DD-MON-YY for Oracle and MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I am having one business requirement where earlier we used to support only Oracle, now we need to extend the support to mariadb(mysql).

We don't have option of maintain 2 different queries for the 2 different databases.
So, we have to form query which is common for both databases.

Now, we stuck here we know that mariadb by default will YYYY-MM-DD and with the help of STR_TO_DATE we have option of converting into other format but STR_TO_DATE won't supported by Oracle.

I am looking out for common function which will support Date format of DD-MON-YY in both Oracle and MySql.

If any one can help us then it will be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are using MySQL and Oracle, then you really need to consider the option of supporting different queries for the two databases.  Different date formats are just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: Create stored procedures/functions to convert to/from the common date format. (Those two products are both less ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: use an ORM to generate equivalent queries for the two backends when possible & fall back on handwritten queries in cases the ORM doesn't support. to reduce

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to work with:

1. ANSI date literals:

   ```
   SELECT DATE '1998-12-25' FROM DUAL
   ```

   They appear to work in MySQL and Oracle (not in e.g. SQL Server, which might be a future concern) and they're great for e.g. insertions but the date produced will still be rendered (possibly differently) to string unless your database library supports transparent conversion to your client language date type.
2. Default date formats:

   Both engines have one. The MySQL one cannot be changed but the Oracle one can.
3. User defined functions:

   If a given system does not have `STR_TO_DATE()` or `DATE_FORMAT()`, write your own. (Again, if you ever need to support to SQL Server you'll need to add a prefix like `dbo.` so it will be a concern.)

*Said that, if you absolutely need SQL code that runs on two different engines you'll soon run into a endless stream of work: sooner or later you'll need to replicate poorly with your client language almost any interesting feature that database could otherwise offer: auto-increment / sequences, check constraints, transactions... You can't even write a cross-platform paginator with plain SQL unless you resort to terribly complicated tricks.*